# How to integrate a function or its derivatives with respect to itself?

Tags: calculus

How do you evaluate the following integrals?

1. $\int f df$
2. $\int f' df$
3. $\int f'' df$

Where $f(x)$ is a function of x, and $f', f''$ are the first and second derivatives with respect to x.

Regarding integral 1, I think that the answer is: $(1/2)f^2$. But I get stack with the other two.

Comment: If it helps: (i) Rewrite $df(x) = f'(x) dx$. (ii) Your answer to (1) is correct, but you should explain how you got it. (iii) The answer to (3) is "similar" to the answer to (1).

Comment: (1) is not quite correct in that you left off the $+C$. You may think this is not a big deal, but I promise you that it will cause issues if you keep forgetting it (not just issues with your teacher - it interfere with your ability to solve problems. (1) translates to $\int f(t)f'(t)\,dt$ (2) translates to $\int (f'(t))^2\,dt$ and (3) translates to $\int f'(t)f''(t)\,dt$. For (2) and (3) I suggest you define $g(t) = f'(t)$ and rewrite them in terms of $g$. That will handle (3) easily. (2) has no simple formula for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As User203940 noted, consider

\begin{equation}
f^{\prime}(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} \Leftrightarrow \mathrm{d}f =  f^{\prime}(x)\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

then you can re-write your integrals as
\begin{align*}
\int g(x)\,\mathrm{d}f = \int g(x)f^{\prime}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

where $g(x)$ denotes $f(x)$, $f^{\prime}(x)$, $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ or any other function of interest. Using, e.g., integartion by parts the integral can be evaluated as

\begin{equation}
\int g(x)f^{\prime}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = g(x)f(x) - \int g^{\prime}(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

For the special case $g(x) = f(x)$, then
\begin{equation}
\int f(x)f^{\prime}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = f(x)f(x) - \int f^{\prime}(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = f^{2}(x) - \int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}f = f^{2}(x) - \frac{1}{2}f^{2}(x) + C = \frac{1}{2}f^{2}(x)
\end{equation}
where in the step $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}f$ the function $f$ itself was considered as an independent variable.

For sure there are more dicussions about similar topics on math.stackexchange.com or mathoverflow. For a more general discussion, I believe the question goes into the direction of Riemann–Stieltjes integral.